# matlab2tikz Invalid Code (13x)

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

I have a question or rather a significant problem with matlab2tikz. When I insert the resulting tikz file into my document and try to compile a get a large number of

```
! Invalid code (13x), should be in the range 0..15.
```

where x may be several numbers such as 0, 5, 10, 15 or 20. 
When I last used it 2 years ago everything was fine. I already updated all relevant packages (pgf, pgfplots, tikzscale) as well as matlab2tikz itself. I downloaded Cygwin and tried the "list and make" option and now I am completely out of my depth. 
I could not even find out what this error is supposed to mean, when I paste it into google I actually get asked to insert a captcha.

Here is a minimal (not-working) example, I would be happy if someone were able to help me.

```
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
name=plot2
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   0\\
0.0096870704600779  0.00501678043448344\\
};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
anchor=below south west
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   0\\
0.0096870704600779  2.43104038793334e-05\\
};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
anchor=above north west
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1,solid,line width=1.5pt]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   0\\
0.0096870704600779  0.00355112896392869\\
};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
anchor=above north west
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1,solid,line width=1.5pt]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   0\\
0.0096870704600779  8.92613493859312e-06\\
0.0193741409201558  3.56608750177765e-05\\
19.9954176771399    0.663181955475221\\
20  0.663230672127747\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

**Update**

While tying to create an example including packages and other relevant bits I found that this error does behave strangely. While pasting my thesis piece by piece into a new document it did not occur even after pasting the whole thing, until it suddenly did. Further experiments suggest some conflict between hyperref, tikzscale and the matlab2tikz option 'nosize' but have not been able to nail it down. I found a workaround compiling all tikz files in a separate document and then inserting the pdf's into the main one.

Unless someone has a bright idea or suggestion I would drop this question for now and just blame the full moon.

Comment: Welcome! Please complete your code so that it produces the error you are reporting when we attempt to compile it. Updating individual packages in isolation is a bit fraught: better make sure your TeX installation as a whole is current.

Comment: no issue on my side. Probably an old TeX installation.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I of course also updated everything which could be in some relation to miktex but to no avail. As stated in my update, I was not able to reliably produce minimal example showing the error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP can't (re)produce code with bug!